# error implementing audio

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a audio app and I would like the audio to keep playing in the back ground.(screen off)

Background mode is enabled on xcode and I implemented "AVAudioSession.sharedInstance" however audio does not keep playing after the screen goes off. Any idea to solve this issue?

```
        var player:AVAudioPlayer!

        init(withStartingClosure block1:@escaping(_ dict:[String:Any],_ index:Int) -> Void,andStopingClosure block2:@escaping(_ index:Int) -> Void,finishedAllClosure block3:((_ finished:Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
            self.didStartPlaying = block1
            self.didStopPlaying = block2
            self.didFinishPlaying = block3
        }
        deinit {
            self.mode = .stopped
        }
    }
        extension AudioPlayer {
        func getURL(ofAudio name:String) -> URL {
            let url = URL(string: name)!
            let nm = url.deletingPathExtension().absoluteString
            let type = url.pathExtension
            let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nm, withExtension: type)!
            return path
        }

        func setupPlayer(withData data:[String:Any]){
            let name = data["audio"] as! String
            var idx = self.currentIndex - 1
            if idx < -1 {
                idx = -1
            }
            print("\nCurrentIndex = \(idx),and Audio is = \(data)")
            let path = self.getURL(ofAudio: name)
            do {
                try self.setupAudioSession()
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path)
                self.player.delegate = self
                if self.player.prepareToPlay() == true {
                    self.player.play()
                    self.didStartPlaying?(data, idx)
                }else{
                    print("----------Can't Play \(data)")
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error!", message: error.localizedDescription, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            }


        }

   // func backgroundSession()
             func backgroundSession() {
                let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                do{
                    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could Call this as a function...

```
func backgroundSession() {
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do{
      try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    }
    catch {  
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. There is no "The View Did Load" in the class i wrote so I cant add it.

Comment: You could try adding it into a function and calling it though.

Comment: I added your code but still receives the same errors :/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the Info.plist the "UIBackgroundModes" key includes the "audio" value.

Moreover, I recommend to work with the AVAudioSession shared instance and AVAudioPlayer instances in the following order:

1. Configure AVAudioSession shared instance.
2. Create first AVAudioPlayer instance and play it.
3. Stop the first.
4. Create second AVAudioPlayer instance and play it.
5. Stop the second.
6. ...

Hope it helps.